# "google.script.run.function" not passing values from htmlservice

Tags: google-apps-script

I understand [issue 1660](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1660) has been marked as fixed but I cannot seem to get any parameters passed from my htmlservice form to my google apps script.  Here's what I have tried:

```
<my html file>
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="aField" id="aField">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick = "sendData()">
</form>

<script>
function sendData() {
   google.script.run.processForm(document.getElementById("myForm"));
}
</script>
</my html file>

<google apps script>
   function processForm(value) {
      var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1234").getRangeByName("testRnage");
      range.setValue(value.aField);
    }
   </google apps script>
```

Using

`<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick = "google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode)">`does not work either.

Both methods result in the following browser error: **"Uncaught ScriptError: TypeError: Cannot call method "setValue" of null."**

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: If you feel that your question (now useless since you discovered that it's a simple typo) clutters up StackOverflow, you are free to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing this successfully :

```
var invoice = new Object();

invoice.customerCode = selectedCustomer.value;
invoice.discount = document.getElementById('discount').value;
invoice.items = blah, blah, blah . . . 

var jsonInvoice = JSON.stringify(invoice);

google.script.run.recordInvoice(jsonInvoice);
```

... with this on the server ...

```
function recordInvoice(jsonInvoice) {
    var theInvoice = eval("(" + jsonInvoice + ")");
    var cust = theInvoice.customerCode;
```

Feel free to ask for elaboration if that seems incomplete.

Comment: I hate to say it but it wasn't working due to a typo in my code.  I was trying to access the defined range as "testRnage" instead of "testRange."  Thanks for your help.  I combed the code over and over and kept missing it.  I'm also new to GAS so I didn't fully understand the error, which actually makes sense now.

Comment: Oh crap -- I saw that "testRnage" but assumed it was a typo while you prepared your post.  Duh, sorry.   Meanwhile, I do strongly suggest you consider using JSON.stringify, your code will become much clearer ans simpler.